# How to use JENA APIs to read data from an owl file

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology

I have tried to write a code that prints the desired contents from an owl file. Here is my code:

```
public String execute()
{
    OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );



    // get an OntClass reference to one of the classes in the model
    // note: ideally, we would delegate this step to Jena's schemagen tool


    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("C:/OOAD-Softwares/workspace4/SemWeb/build/src/main/resources/semrailwaysv2.owl");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } // or any windows path
    m.read(in, null);



   OntClass ontclass = m.getOntClass(SOURCE_URL+"#RailwayStation");

    ExtendedIterator iterator =  ontclass.listInstances();


   while(iterator.hasNext())
   {
       Object obj = iterator.next();
       System.out.println("Object : "+obj.toString());
   }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Here I am able to get the number of instances of the desired class from my owl file by directly using the listInstances() method as an iterator without assigning, but I am unable to get the various property values for each instance. How should I proceed to do this? Also if I use the parameterized version of ExtendedIterator,

```
ExtendedIterator<OntClass> it = ontclass.listInstances();
```

is giving an error saying

```
The type ExtendedIterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <OntClass>
```

How should I proceed?

### Edit

I have updated the code, still same problem.

Comment: If Java says ExtendedIterator is not generic, then most likely you have an old copy of Jena on the classpath.

Comment: I am using jena-2.6.4.. seemingly the latest version

Comment: "I am unable to get the various property values for each instance."  I don't see where in the code you're trying to do that.  Once you call next() to get an instance, can't you just listProperties to iterate over the statements of which it's the subject?

Comment: 2.12.1 is the latest version. See http://jena.apache.org/download/index.html  But 2.6.4 has generics so it still looks like you have some classpath issues.